# Implementing One-Shot Attention Example

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, artificial-intelligence, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to implement a one-shot attention example: [this](https://github.com/drspiffy/Concurrence)

As you can see, there's a `data/train_arithmetic.tsv` file, which has arithmetic operations in X (2+70) and a result in Y (72).

I understand the example code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(GRU(hidden_size, return_sequences=True), merge_mode='concat',
                        input_shape=(None, input_size)))
model.add(Concurrence())
model.add(RepeatVector(max_out_seq_len + 1))
model.add(GRU(hidden_size * 2, return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(output_dim=output_size, activation="softmax")))
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="rmsprop")
```

But I'm not quite sure which values have the `hidden_size`, `input_size`, `output_size` and `max_out_seq_len` for this example.

So I defined it so:

```
hidden_size = 1
input_size = 1  # this is maybe 3
output_size = 1
max_out_seq_len = 1
```

And then I got the x-y_train and x-y_set:

```
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(data_set[:, 0:1], data_set[:, 1],
                                                    test_size=0.25, random_state=87)
```

With the `np.random.seed` and everything.

I printed it to be sure and it yields:

```
x_train: ['38620+1776']
x_test: ['11+52']
y_train: 40396
y_test: 63
```

Which for me, makes a lot of sense, and I could say it seems good. (I might be of course maybe wrong)

Then I fit_transform it:

```
fitted_x_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
fitted_x_test = scaler.fit_transform(X_test)
```

And it yields:

```
x_train_fitted: 56867
x_test_fitted: 12870
```

Which looks good again.

I used the normal `EarlyStopping`:

```
early_stop_criteria = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0,
                                                    patience=20, verbose=0, mode='auto')
```

And then tried to fit it:

```
model_fitted = model.fit(fitted_x_train, Y_train, epochs=1000, verbose=0,
                         batch_size=X_train.shape[0], initial_epoch=0, callbacks=[early_stop_criteria],
                         validation_split=0.2)
```

But I'm getting this error:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected bidirectional_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (75000, 1)

and it makes sense to me, because it's waiting for `11` + `+` + `52` and not just `11+52`. But I actually don't have a clue anymore...

Maybe I'm doing the whole thing wrong and there is another way to implement it, or maybe I'm on the right way and I just have to get (75000, 3)with the split, which seems not so trivial for me, because there could be `-11+52`

Maybe someone implemented the example before or at least know how it should work. I'm clearly missing something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

I was completely wrong.

The hidden_size, I chose 128.

As it is a seq2seq problem, the input size should be the length of the whole vocabulary, which in my case I added 2 more, because of 'ZERO' and 'UNKNOWN'.

The output size is the same as the input size.

The max_out_seq_len is the length of the sentence with biggest length.

As it's an attention problem, this:

```
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(data_set[:, 0:1], data_set[:, 1],test_size=0.25, random_state=87)
```

doesn't make sense.

that's why I changed for this:

```
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(data_set[:, 0:],
                                                    [str(i[0].split("\t", 1)[1]) for i in data_set[:]],
                                                    test_size=0.3, random_state=87)
```

x looks so: `x_train: ['1-116\t-115']`
and y so  : `y_train: -115`

this is also an error:

```
model_fitted = model.fit(fitted_x_train, Y_train, epochs=1000, verbose=0,
                         batch_size=X_train.shape[0], initial_epoch=0, callbacks=[early_stop_criteria],
                         validation_split=0.2)
```

should be so:

```
model_output = model.fit(x_sequences, y_sequences, epochs=10000, verbose=1, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                             initial_epoch=0, callbacks=[early_stop_criteria], validation_split=0.2)
```

where `BATCH_SIZE = 128`

And I was getting the error, because `Bidirectional` needs a 3D array.

so I resolved it so:

```
def process_data(word_sentences, max_len, word_to_ix):
    # Vectorizing each element in each sequence
    sequences = np.zeros((len(word_sentences), max_len, len(word_to_ix)))
    for i, sentence in enumerate(word_sentences):
        for j, word in enumerate(sentence):
            sequences[i, j, word] = 1.
    return sequences
```

I was interested in just the attention that's why `"1+1\t2" => "2"`

With the data of the gitHub repository, I'm getting in the 6th Epoch

```
56000/56000 [==============================] - 79s - loss: 0.0154 - acc: 0.9955 - val_loss: 0.0030 - val_acc: 0.9991
```

so it seems to work pretty well. I gotta try with more difficult data.